# optimize octree octant_determination function in c++

Tags: c++, octree

I am building a spacial octree. In order to determine in which branch/octant a certain point (x,y,z) should be placed, I use this function:

```
if (x>x_centre) {
    xsign = 1;
}
else {
    xsign = 0;
}

if (y>y_centre) {
    ysign = 1;
}
else {
    ysign = 0;
}

if (z>z_centre) {
    zsign = 1;
}
else {
    zsign = 0;
}

return xsign + 2*ysign + 4*zsign;
```

It returns a number between 0 and 7 unique for every octant. It turns out this snippet is called a big many times. It gets quite time consuming when building large trees.

Is there any easy way to speed this proces up?

This allready gives a 30 percent speed up:

```
xsign = x>x_centre;
ysign = y>y_centre;
zsign = z>y_centre;

return xsign + 2*ysign + 4*zsign;
```

Any other tips?

Comment: use of ternary operator may be an option

Comment: Two things: You can mark the function as `inline` hoping that the compiler will inline the code at the call-site. Secondly remember that `true` is equivalent to `1` and `false` is equivalent to `0`. The last bit will help you discard the `if` statements.

Comment: If I have to place lets say ten million items in my tree, the average depth is log(ten million)/log(8) = 8. So I inevitably have to call this function eighty million times.

What do you mean by mispredictions?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks! That allready gave an improvement of 30 percent.

Comment: instead of using multiplies, use shifts: 2 * a = a << 1, 4 * a = a << 2, etc. (only works with +ve numbers)

Comment: @renger you also removed the branches with the new code.

Comment: @renger You removed the if statements, which I suspect plays a good part in the 30% improvement. But only profiling can tell http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor

Comment: That final version might be as good as it gets. Have a look at the assembly code the compiler is creating (and post it here).

Comment: @concept3d: There is a chance that the compiler has got rid of the branches entirely - for example, on a IA32 there is a setg instruction which sets a byte to 0 or 1 depending on the state of the flags.

Comment: @Skizz, I think you are right. I am using Dev-C++ for Windows, and have no clue how to acces the assembly code :(

Comment: @Skizz Good to know, I think as you said showing the assembly will tell if this code can be improved.

Comment: @renger: One way to find the compiler output is to run the code in a debugger, place a breakpoint on the code in question, when execution stops, the debugger should have an option to view the assembly.

Comment: `return (x>x_centre ? 1 : 0) | (y>y_centre ? 2 : 0) | (z>z_centre ? 4 : 0)` might be faster